# How to align and pin to buttom widget in BIRT?

Tags: eclipse, birt

How to align and pin to buttom a widget in BIRT Report Designer (in Eclipse)? I can find properties for aligning the text inside text widget, but how to align widget itself, as to sheet? I gazed up at *Advanced properties*, but I didn't find anything helpful, and I tried to change *Style* of widget, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "align to the bottom of the *page*" - this is not possible with BIRT.